# intellisense imports components from "bootstrap" instead of "react-bootstrap"

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense, react-bootstrap

Hi I am not sure if this is about my VScode settings or the way I installed bootstrap. I used yarn to install react-bootstrap and bootstrap as show in react-bootstrap's documentation. But when I type <Button and press enter it automatically imports <Button component like this:

```
import { Button } from "bootstrap";
```

this doesn't work. I have to manually fix it to

```
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
```

is it a bug or did I do something with wrong order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have inline suggestions turned on (Preferences -> Text Editor -> Suggestions), you'll  see that Intellisense provides import suggestions alphabetically — first by identifier then by package.

With inline suggestions, you're given a list you can navigate through to select whichever option you're looking for. In this case, you'd type `But` and it would show the `react-bootstrap` `Button` as the second option, so you'd press down arrow and tab to accept that option.

Comment: I don't know if it is because i turned my computer off yesterday and turned on today but yes. You are right. Yesterday it was not showing the react-bootstrap option. Now it is on the second row. At least it is showing now.